# Creating a table on Power BI

Tags: powerbi, relation

I'm new to Power BI, and I'm trying to create the following Table.

[image: Table Schema]

And the table used for it is like:

```
DATE date,
NIT nvarchar(50),
CLIENT nvarchar(50),
ID_EMPLOYEE int,
NM_EMPLOYEE nvarchar(70),
AREA nvarchar(50),
PROJECT nvarchar(50),
COST_TYPE nvarchar(50),
COST decimal(18,2)
```

The cost type defines if the value is positive or negative, but I want to 'split' the rows with cost type 'income' from the 'employees' and 'computers' ones. Then put the values into the table as shown above and make some calculations.

All the values are on the same table.

The complicated part however, comes with the slider part, as they must be values from the Area, Client, Employee, etc...fields.

When browsing on Internet I couldn't find a clear way to do this. I made several attempts with relations but since I don't know them very well I couldn't make it(created multiple tables filtering the value).

If someone can help me to do this I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

To do this :

- you should have column Month
- Then you can use **Matrix** of power Bi and mention:
        **as rows** : customer, employee, project... |
        **as columns** : Month |
        **as value** : cost

[image: here an example]

Comment: The concept is not bad. However, employee, project and computers are not fields, are values from the Cost type field.